# IE7 and script error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

My website URL: http://3d-koncept.pl

On IE8 everything is ok, but on IE7 there is some problem with JS gallery script. I don't have this version of IE and I don't know what it is. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this website?

Regards.

Comment: You can open developer tools (or something) in IE. It is F11 or F12. The new window will pop up. There will be an option to force an older engine in the browser. You may install the virtual machine with older IE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view what the website looks like to IE7 users by enabling the compatibility mode:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Here you find some ways to setup a testing environment.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/02/reliable-cross-browser-testing-part-1-internet-explorer/)

And this is the problem:

[image: IE7 Problems]